# How is glint rendering done in Ray Tracing?

Tags: rendering, raytracing, physically-based, normal-mapping, ray

How is **glint rendering** done with ray tracing in the photo below? **Is it just a simple normal map?**

[image]

I found a paper online that describes the exact same method used in the photo above but I have no idea what's going on, especially with all the jargon being thrown around. Here's the link:
**https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~lingqi/publications/paper_glints.pdf**

Comment: It's an extremely high-resolution normal map, with many texels per screen pixel, and the paper introduces a special technique to calculate highlights from all normals in a screen pixel at once. Can you be more specific about what you understand already and where you're getting lost? It's hard to help otherwise.

Comment: That explanation was quite helpful, where I am getting lost is the part about 4D Gaussians & Position Normal Distributions. What are they & what do they do? In the paper they show the benefits of their method as opposed to just a simple normal map.